# CSS a list so it's the same size

Tags: html, css

I have some sort of tab using the following format :

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Four Long Word</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Five</a></li>
</ul>
```

However I don't know how to make all < li > the same height such that when active and the color different the box not to look disjonted.

This is the jsfidle : http://jsfiddle.net/BzTjb/9/

The js code was taken from another fiddle and it's not the one I'm using in the site, it's just for demonstration here since it's simple.

Comment: Are you looking for that http://jsfiddle.net/BzTjb/11/ or i don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `display` property of the `li` to `table-cell` and remove the `float: left`, so the CSS for the `li` will look like this:

```
li {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BzTjb/12/)

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot !! Had tried the table-cell but had forgotten to remove the float.

Answer (score 0):

The `Four Long Word` link is wrapped because the container tab has a fixed width of `300px`. Expanding this width will allow it to display in a single line. Doing this alone won't be a pretty, one-step solution, however; you might need to alter some padding as well. It's up to you to determine exactly how you want it to look.

Alternatively, you can try `width: auto;` to give it a responsive width.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying a pixel width for the tabs, just use width:auto and the tab will be the correct width based on the content.

```
ul#tabs {
    width: auto; list-style: none;
    display: block; clear: both;
}
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BzTjb/10/)

Comment: I know that already, that's very obvious :p . Setting the display property of the li to table-cell and removing the float: left did the trick !

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options but all depends of what you really want to achieve. I usually do the following:

```
li a {
    display: block;
    width: 300px; /* Or any width you want to fit your content */
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;  /* All this is optional */
    margin-right: 15px; /* All this is optional */
}
```

or

```
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px; /* Or any width you want to fit your content */
    padding: 10px 15px;  /* All this is optional */
    margin-right: 15px; /* All this is optional */
}
```

Comment: Neither of these work; they overflow on top of the 5th anchor tag.

Comment: This is just a snippet. You might need to increase the width of the "ul" and the container for the list to fit correctly.

Comment: Then it should really be noted as a partial answer or expanded upon.

Comment: I disagree it was obviously a partial answer. Answers on SO should be as clear and complete as possible. Poor or partial answers risk being downvoted.

Comment: Well, that's up to the users here to judge. If you have a better answer then post it and shut up. Let the people vote for whatever is best. Isn't the point of this website?

Comment: I am a user here, and I have in fact posted a better answer.

Comment: Obviously when I did this it just set it as an example so the width being 300px is just so you could see the effect I was referring to.

Comment: Found my answer but nevertheless, thanks a lot for your response !!